# Javascript открывается позже html

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Всем привет , не силен в JS , залил на сайт слайдер но , он открывается позже самой html страницы , гдето на 0.5 секунд при загрузке , не подскажете как сделать чтобы javascript код выполнялся раньше чем html / css , чтобы загрузился сначало js а потом уже body html , пробовал засунуть скрипт в header но не помогает.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
    });
});
```

Comment: Хьюстон, мы потеряли это поколение. ТС, Вы хоть пытались подумать - что у Вас в коде выполняется? Функция `jQuery.ready` ждёт не весны или любви :)

Comment: Я знаю что выполняется , но не знаю js ,  поэтому и спросил как сделать так что бы выполнялся сначало js а потом html . так как сам не разбираюсь в js

Comment: А почему тогда вопрос? `jQuery` ждет заполнения DOM, что невозможно без `HTML`. Почитайте: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_DOM

Comment: Я хочу понять , возможно ли сделать вместо $document ready , что - либо обратное , которое не будет ждать заполнения? а загрузтся сразу

Comment: Зачем? Ваш код использует работу с DOM, если не подождать пока он загрузится - скрипт упадёт с ошибкой.

Comment: дело в том что , есть элементы которые позиционируется слева от слайдера , и когда слайдер не загрузился они слева окна ,  а как загрузятся отодвигаются направо , и нелепое позиционирование вовремя просмотра страницы получается

Comment: Скрывайте их до загрузки слайдера.

Comment: Хьюстон прием......)  Господа ну что вы, человек хочет загрузить слайдер до того как загрузиться объектная модель документа, и под этот слайдер воткнуть потом разметку, оригинальная идея, пусть пробует... как говорится: -Век живи, век учись. А все таки попробуйте слайдеру задать обертку с фиксированной шириной что бы элементы не прыгали.

Comment: нельзя фиксированную ширину задавать , слайдер резиновый должен быть

Comment: @AntonEssential, Хьюстон на связи. Как он достанет элемент из DOM, если он ещё не готов? А если DOM строится **столь** долго, что нужно ждать хотя бы элемента, то с кодом явно что-то не так и лучше сразу всё нормально сделать.

Comment: Да с кодом все в порядке , просто забыл заплатить за свой интернет , сижу на соседском в 2 мегабита)))
Вот и адаптирую под бомже инет)

Comment: @Other Конечно никак) ну лично я не знаю, по этому и написал пусть пробует. Ну рас слайдер резина, задайте ширину в процентах и задайте padding в пару пикселей пока контента нет, что бы обертка толкала правый блок

Comment: пробовал все , задавал и в процентах и пикселях , но блок тупо не появляется пока не загрузится js , впринципе я уже решил эту проблему тем что , как подсказали выше , Скрыл прыгающие элементы  до загрузки слайдера , теперь ничего не плавает и загружается одновременно.
Еще раз благодарю всех , кто откликнулся в столь поздний час)

Answer (score 1):

Подключай скрипт в header. Если поключать в конце документа, то он и будет грузиться в порядке объявления. Т.е. вначале загрузится все, что было до него и только потом он сам.

Comment: я подключил его в header . грузится он все равно позже чем остальные.

Comment: Еще вариант, что у тебя скрипт находится внутри функции window.onload или $( document ).ready(). То есть все, что внутри них, выполняется только после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: и что сделать , убрать их? А если уберу на работу самого скрипта не повлияет?

Comment: выложил сам скрипт наверх

Comment: Не убирай. Просто поменяй document на тег, при загрузке которого должен срабатывать скрипт. https://api.jquery.com/ready/ вот немного мануала.

Comment: У тебя скрипт выполняется только после полной загрузке страницы) этому способствует  $( document ).ready(). Дословно читая "при готовности документа". Вот скрипт и ждет, когда вся страница загрузится. А тебе надо при готовности не документа, а готовности нужного тебе тега.

Comment: @Nikolay, лучше не стрелять по воробьям, ожидая **только** нужный тег, а подождать весь DOM. При грамотной загрузке, он быстро будет готов.

Comment: @Other это конечно. Но вот у автора, как я понял, страница очень перегружена, что долго грузится. И тут как ты грамотно не грузи, скрипт все равно будет ждать весь документ

Comment: Использовать столь тяжёлую страницу - верный повод подумать о подгрузке небольшой части, каркаса, а остальное догружать AJAX'сом. Слайдер всё равно может упасть, если что-то в скрипте попытается обратиться куда-то, что ещё не загружено (не работал с этим плагином, не знаю).

Comment: Я не понимаю дилемы автора. Ты хотел, что-то обратное, которое не будет ждать загрузки всего dom, а только нужного. Я выше сказал, как это сделать. Так если вопрос еще какой остался по этому поводу, то лучше задать

Comment: @Other не хочу обижать начинающего автора, но о каком ajax речь? Человек пытается хоть как-то подгрузить скрипт и не понимает особо jquery. И ему я крайне рекомендую узнать, что грузит страницу. Картинки большого разрешения, скорее всего.

Comment: DOM строится раньше тяжёлых картинок. Запаздывание DOM говорит о большом количестве HTML для разбора и зависящих стилей/скриптов.

Comment: @Other а, да, вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый способ построить и отобразить слайдер это подключить все ваши js файлы в блоке head страницы.

Отобразить слайдер до остального содержимого страницы так просто не удастся. Только если специально скрывать остальное содержимое до момента когда слайдер готов.

Comment: так он и стоит раньше всех , позже него идет другой слайдер уже на css.. но он загружается быстрее чем js . который в html до него расположен

Comment: При подключении скриптов используются атрибуты async или defer?
Советую прочитать эту статью (про порядок выполнение скриптов на странице) - http://learn.javascript.ru/external-script

Comment: про async знаю , используется , но всеравно html загружается раньше чем js

Comment: Можно попробовать следующее, хотя не советую использовать такие решения.

Заменить этот код: https://jsbin.com/nadaqevabe/1/edit?js

На этот: https://jsbin.com/casujujuye/1/edit?js

Т.е. не ждать полного построения DOM.

Comment: ваш вариант работает , спасибо , а почему не советуете??

Comment: Т.к. в важный момент когда страница строится, рендерится мы запускаем таймер, который выполняется с интервалом 20 миллисекунд. Может быть это немного затормозит отображение страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Решил тем , что , как подсказали выше скрыл прыгающие контейнеры до загрузки страницы также как и слайдер , вот код кому надо будет.

```
<div class="hide2">
              <div class="skip"><div class="soccontainer">
                      <a href="#"><div class="spancontent4"></div></a>
                      <a href="#"><div class="spancontent5"></div></a>
                      <a href="#"><div class="spancontent6"></div></a>

                  </div></div>
              </div>


       <script>

window.onload = function() {

var div2 = document.querySelector('.hide2');

div2 && div2.classList.remove('hide2')

         };

</script>
```